# Name suggestions stopped working in Picasa 3.9

Tags: windows-7, photos, picasa, tags

Today, I've upgraded to Picasa 3.9 and name suggestions stopped working as before.

When I was adding person to a photo, there was a list of suggested names ordered by highest probability. The same thing happened when I started typing in "Add a name" field. So, when I typed letter 'N', all persons starting with that letter appeared and I could choose one of them :)

Since I updated to 3.9, list of persons do not appears under person's face I want to tag (as in below screenshot):

[image: There is no list under person's face I want to tag.]

Currently, if I want to tag person:

1. I type name or part of name,
2. press Enter,
3. `People` window appears with filtered names,
4. and finally, I click `Choose` button.

Before, I just selected person from the dropdown list and that was everything I needed to do.

My question is—How to have functionality of list with persons when tagging the photo back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Picasa helped with the problem.